# How to disable the single view / search /archive page for a already-built custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

There is a plugin that adds a custom post type called "magicai-documents". I want to disable the single view, search, and archive pages (**every area of frontend**) for an **already-built custom post type**.

I know I can use `'publicly_queryable' => false` when creating a custom post type, but since this custom post type is created by a plugin, I can't update the `register_post_type` code. What is the best way to disable the single view, search, and archive pages for an already built custom post type?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I actually wanted to ask, what plugin is it and did it not provide a UI/setting which allows you to change the post type args?

Comment: @SallyCJ Your solution is worked. Thanks. The plugin name is "MagicAI for WordPress"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this custom post type is created by a plugin, I can't update the
> `register_post_type` code

You can use either the [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) or [`register_<post type>_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_post_type_args/) hook to filter the post type args like the `publicly_queryable` in your case. See an example below which uses the former hook, where I also set `exclude_from_search` to `true` to exclude posts with the `magicai-documents` post type from front end search results.

```php
<?php
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_filter_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'magicai-documents' === $post_type ) {
        $args['publicly_queryable']  = false;
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = true;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

If the post type should only be made public on the admin side, then you can set the `public` arg to `false`, and then set `show_ui` and `show_in_nav_menus` to `true`.

- See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters.

Alternatively, you could hook on an action like `template_redirect` and do a [conditional tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) check like `if ( is_singular( 'magicai-documents' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'magicai-documents' ) ) { display a 404 error or (do) something else }`, and/or you could filter the `WP_Query` args using the `pre_get_posts` action, but changing the appropriate post type args is *much easier*.